# How can I convert an AI file to a CDR file?

Tags: file-conversion

Assume I have an AI file, Adobe Illustrator CS 5 and no CorelDraw. How can I convert this AI file to CDR file? What is the fastest and cheapiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of CorelDRAW? What's the workflow?

.CDR is a proprietary format, so I'm not aware of any proper supported exporters. The [sK1 project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK1_%28program%29) reverse-engineered the format, and claims to have the best support. But since recent versions of CorelDRAW can [import Adobe Illustrator CS4 files](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Content/1153321236837), I think you would get the best results to just save it as .ai and import it into CorelDRAW.

Comment: I know it and I don't know the version of CorelDRAW. I have to send my logo to a festival and there are several strict requirements for file format. The matter is quite urgent, nevertheless thanx for the prompt responce.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be what you are looking for:
http://en.allexperts.com/q/Adobe-Illustrator-1027/Converting-Illustrator-Corel-Draw.htm

Comment: That article is five years old, so I'd be careful about what features you'd lose saving in legacy formats and later versions of CorelDRAW have better support of later Illustrator versions.